# Lotus Embedded view and chrome browser

Tags: lotus-notes

I am trying to open a form in browser ( CHROME ) which has embedded view in it, but it shows blank nothing opens. I set embedded view's property to show as Java Applet in when displaying over web.

Google chrome does not support embedded view ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to show embedded views: As Java Applet or as Pure HTML (depending of the options for the embedded view in designer).

The Java Applet is seen as insecure by some / most browsers since a long time and will not work anymore.

If you need an embedded view, then you need to switch to HTML- View (that is quite ugly) or rewrite the page as XPage with all its possibilities.